# How to begin text a certain distance from the right margin

Tags: formatting, margins

As the date changes in length each day, I find myself manually modifying the `hspace` distance to the beginning of the signature line every time I generate a document.  Can anyone think of a better way to do this -- e.g., perhaps with the signature line beginning a certain distance from the right-hand margin?  The signature line needs to be aligned with the three lines of text underneath.  Using `minipage` seems to be overkill, and I thought perhaps a simpler solution may exist -- e.g., `\begin-x-inches-from-right-margin`.

```
\hspace*{3in}Respectfully submitted,\
~\\
~\
DATE: ~ \today \hspace*{34mm} By: ~ \makebox[3in]{\hrulefill}

\hspace*{3.5in}TYPED NAME OF PERSON SIGNING

\hspace*{3.5in}Attorney for Respondent,

\hspace*{3.5in}NAME OF LITIGANT
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
\\

~\\
~\
```

use `\vspace{something}`

`\begin-x-inches-from-right-margin.` is

```
  \hspace*{\fill}\makebox[2in][l]{ABC}
```

Which will put the start of `ABC` 2in from the right margin.
But I didn't understand your layout description enough to suggest how to use it here.

Comment: That works perfectly -- thank you very much -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)  `DATE: ~ \today \hspace*{\fill}\makebox[3in][l]{By: ~ \hrulefill}\hspace*{25mm}`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [`tabbing`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex/ltx-58.html) environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
    DATE: ~ \today \hspace*{34mm} By: ~ \= \makebox[3in]{\hrulefill}\\
    \> TYPED NAME OF PERSON SIGNING\\
    \> Attorney for Respondent,\\
    \> NAME OF LITIGANT\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Short explanation: `\=` sets a tabulator, with `\>` you can jump to this tabulator.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing an alternative solution.  Greatly appreciated!